# Is it possible to add varying buffer based on attribute in geopandas?

Tags: python, buffer, geospatial, spatial, geopandas

I have the following GeoSeries:

`print(zambia_grid)`

```
voltage_kV, geometry, buffer_value                                                             
88.0,        MULTILINESTRING ((662448.559 8288872.590, 6625...,  660.0   
132.0,       MULTILINESTRING ((662368.932 8288816.909, 6623...,  142.0   
220.0,       MULTILINESTRING ((632159.980 8609158.729, 6321...,  990.0   
330.0,       MULTILINESTRING ((662612.310 8288970.288, 6626...,  220.0
```

I have tried creating a buffer:

`zambia_grid_buffer = zambia_grid.buffer(distance = zambia_grid['buffer_value'])`

However when I try to plot this, I get the following error:

'Polygon' object is not subscriptable

... is it possible to have varying buffers in geopandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting from GeoPandas version 0.5, you should be able to pass an array of series of values to `buffer` for the `distance` argument, to have varying buffer sizes.

Using the built-in countries dataset as dummy example:

```py
>>> df = geopandas.read_file(geopandas.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres"))
>>> df
    pop_est      continent       name iso_a3  gdp_md_est                                           geometry
0    920938        Oceania       Fiji    FJI      8374.0  MULTIPOLYGON (((180.00000 -16.06713, 180.00000...
1  53950935         Africa   Tanzania    TZA    150600.0  POLYGON ((33.90371 -0.95000, 34.07262 -1.05982...
2    603253         Africa  W. Sahara    ESH       906.5  POLYGON ((-8.66559 27.65643, -8.66512 27.58948...
3  35623680  North America     Canada    CAN   1674000.0  MULTIPOLYGON (((-122.84000 49.00000, -122.9742...
..      ...            ...        ...    ...         ...                                             

>>> df.buffer(distance=df['pop_est'])
0      POLYGON ((-920362.560 -15501.816, -921118.000 ...
1      POLYGON ((-1110993.428 53939492.982, 4253453.0...
2      POLYGON ((-8.666 603280.656, 58859.799 600401....
3      POLYGON ((-35623475.484 26100.474, -35623805.6...
...
```